# How to effectively use Vim: wildmenu

Tags: vim

I'm a bit confused about the use of Vim's menus. I have `set wildmenu` and `set wildmode=list:longest,full` but I don't understand for the life of me how to invoke and use the completion feature.

Is this feature useful? Why and how? What kind of completion does this do exactly? In other words, what determines the completion list content?

Any tips and example usages would be appreciated.

Comment: I have `set wildmenu`. And find it quite useful. I don't have to tab a  lot if the item i wan't doesn't show on the hint bar.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`wildmenu` and `wildmode` are used for command line completion. The simplest way to try it would be with `:color <Tab>`: the command line is "expanded" vertically with a list of all the colorschemes available on your machine displayed in columns *and* an horizontal strip that you can navigate with `<Tab>` (forward) and `<S-Tab>` (backward).

The behaviour of command line completion and `wildmenu` are dependant on `wildmode`.

See `:help wildmode` and `:help wildmenu` for more details.

Comment: So what I'm getting is it's autocompletion for vim commands! Which makes more sense. Is it able to go beyond that? Perhaps syntax detection to autocomplete function/variable names within, say, .cpp files?

Comment: No the `wildmode`/`wildmenu` combo can't do anything beyond command line completion. Vim has another mechanism for code completion called "omni-completion". Read `:help omni-completion` for more info.

Comment: this is a good point. thanks. code complete is another thing. if it helps. ALE or Coc (conquerer of code) uses another form of popup menus; which is a completely different thing.

Answer (score 72):

Probably the most comfortable option, at least for me is:

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest:full,full
```

That means that on first `<Tab>` it will complete to the longest common string and will invoke wildmenu (a horizontal and unobtrusive little menu). On next `<Tab>` it will complete the first alternative and it will start to cycle through the rest. You can go back and forth with `<Tab>` and `<S-Tab>` respectively.

An awesome example on how wildmenu is very useful, is to complete buffers, use the config I posted and then try:

`:b<Tab>`

Comment: Can you explain how does it work? The help page doesn't say anything about the `:`.

Comment: It's described in the vim help: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'wildmode' (but you have to look into `wildmode`, and not `wildmenu`)

Comment: Do you mean `:b <Tab>` rather than `:b<Tab>` ?

Comment: Yeahhhhh! Thanks a lot. It took me a long time to find this answer, because I didn't know how to describe the desired behaviour to Google. Cool!

Answer (score 25):

My favorite is

```
set wildmenu
set wildmode=longest:list,full
```

First tab will complete to longest string and show the the match list, then second tab will complete to first full match and open the wildmenu.

Answer (score 8):

`:set wildmode=list:longest` allows you to expand the wildmenu.

`:set wildmenu` allows you to use `<Left>` or `<Right>` to navigate through the completion lists.

Comment: Is there a way so that if you hit tab, you could scroll through the completion lists?

Comment: just `:set wildmenu=list:full` instead.

Comment: Linh: This is so close to what I want; I might not have been clear with my previous question. Is there a way so you could scroll through the **expanded wildmenu**? This functionality's similar to zsh: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GvC4A.png

Comment: @hlin117, unfortunately I haven't seen that feature implemented in Vim. If it's only for command, Unite has an interface for it (think "Goto Anything")...

Answer (score 0):

You may want to config `wildoptions`. Please refer to this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38054/40405) on Vi and Vim Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I use `set wildmenu=full:lastused` (not documented in help) which follows recent buffer history (according to `:ls t` order). Something I appreciate the most.

The navigation principle is the same as `set wildmenu=full` similar to `=longest:full,full` but with the advantage of completing the first full match immediately (whereas `longest:full,full` first only completes a common part and you still have to press Tab again to select first item).